# HTML - Display image on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have this div class:

```
<div id="object1">
    <div class="title" onmouseover="hoverImage(event)">SPT 3</div>
</div>
```

And outside of that div, I have another div with a image:

```
<div class="hover_img" id="hover_img">
    <img src="img/sptgoal.PNG">
</div>
```

CSS code to center the image:

```
.hover_img {
    position:relative;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    z-index: 99;
}

.hover_img img {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display:none;
}
```

I only want the image to be visible when hovering the div. This is the Javascript code I have:

```
function hoverImage() {
    var x = document.getElementById("hover_img");
    x.style.display = "block";
}
```

But when hovering the mouse over, nothing shows up. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `document.getElementById("hover_img")` you don't show the image, but the container around it (`hover_img`). But you have hidden the image (`.hover_img img`) in your CSS.

Use `document.querySelectorAll("#hover_img>img")` for selecting your image. [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) will return a NodeList, so you have to use `x[0]` for selecting the first element in list.

```js
function hoverImage(event) {
  var x = document.querySelectorAll("#hover_img>img");
  var sDisplay = (event.type === "mouseout") ? "none" : "block";
  x[0].style.display = sDisplay;
}
```

```css
.hover_img {
    position:relative;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    z-index: 99;
}

.hover_img img {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="object1">
    <div class="title" onmouseover="hoverImage(event)" onmouseout="hoverImage(event)">SPT 3</div>
</div>

<div class="hover_img" id="hover_img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! But why doesn't the image goes away when not hovering anymore?

Comment: There is no event for hiding the image. Check my answer, i've edited it.
Now there is a onmouseout event in div tag and in hoverImage function it is checked which event is called

Answer (score 1):

problem is on element selector you need to select image element for change display property not div tag.
i hope it's help full

> Blockquote

```js
function hoverImage() {
    var x = document.getElementById("hover_img");
    x.children[0].style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.hover_img {
    position:relative;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    z-index: 99;
}

.hover_img img {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="object1">
    <div class="title" onmouseover="hoverImage(event)">SPT 3</div>
</div>
<div class="hover_img" id="hover_img">
    <img src="img/sptgoal.PNG">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must select another id for img:

```html
<div class="hover_img" id="hover_img">
    <img src="img/sptgoal.PNG" id="image1">
</div>
```

and use this id in your java script:

```js
function hoverImage() {
    var x = document.getElementById("image1");
    x.style.display = "block";
}
```